# How to add the manager in email after getting the name in designer 2013 workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I have a sharepoint designer 2013 workflow. I need to get the manager details of the user and include them in a corresponding mail.I have got the manager name using the 'call http web service' action. Now how do I include the name in the corresponding email?

Comment: Are u want to send email to manager?

Answer (score 2):

Assign the value the web service returns to a workflow variable - once you have that, you can include that variable as part of the email body (in the Email Composer window) by using the 'Add/Change Lookup' button and selecting the variable as the lookup.

Answer (score 2):

i think that this is intended as an email recipient which, would be done in the same way (if the web service is receiving that information).

Select the address book in the To/CC option within the define email message window.

Workflow lookup for user, > then find the value from your web service lookup.